# How to force maxima to evaluate a sum? (Evaluation Logic)

Tags: evaluation, maxima

```
(%i1)   load("distrib");
(%o1)   "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/maxima/5.46.0_11/share/maxima/5.46.0/share/distrib/distrib.mac"

(%i2)   T1: sum( pdf_binomial(si,SM,p) * p^2 , si, 0, SM ) $

(%i3)   float(ev(T1, [SM=7,p=0.3]));
(%o3)   sum(binomial(7.0,si)*0.7^(7-si)*0.3^(si+2),si,0.0,7.0)

(%i6)   SM:7 $  float(ev(T1, [p=0.3])); kill(SM) $
(%o5)   sum(binomial(7.0,si)*0.7^(7-si)*0.3^(si+2),si,0.0,7.0)

(%i9)   SM: 7 $ T2: sum( pdf_binomial(si,SM,p) * p^2 , si, 0, SM ) $
    ev(T2, [p=0.3]);
(%o9)   0.08999999999999997
```

if I define SM before I define the expression (T2), it "works" (evaluates to a number).  However, maxima no longer gives numerical values if SM is defined after T1 is defined.  Not shown, if I define T2 as T1 (`T2: T1`), I believe maxima internally stores the symbol T1 into T2, not the expression that is in T1, and this again does not evaluate.  it's somehow about context.  all ok --- I just need to know how to force evaluation when I need to.

advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maxima represents partially-evaluated expressions as so-called noun expressions. Many mathematical functions return noun expressions when the arguments aren't specific enough to permit complete evaluations. `sum`, `integrate`, `diff`, `limit`, etc. return noun expressions; programming functions such as `length`, `first`, `op`, etc., complain with an error message if arguments aren't specific enough.

Nouns can be "verbified" via `ev(expr, nouns)`. You can also nounify just one operator (if there's more than one nounified expression present) by saying the name of the operator, e.g. `ev(expr, sum)` to verbify just `sum`. In this case, the appropriate incantation is:

```
ev(T2, SM = 7, p = 0.3, nouns);
```

You can explicitly construct a noun expression via the single quote `'` applied to an operator, e.g. `'integrate(sin(x), x)`.

Comment: still too mysterious.  `float(ev( sum( pdf_binomial(si,SM,p) * p^2 , si, 0, SM ), [SM=7,p=0.3]))` gives 0.09.  but `T2: sum( pdf_binomial(si,SM,p) * p^2 , si, 0, SM );` and then `float(ev( T2, [SM=7,p=0.3] ))` do not.  once I have T2, what do I need to do to get the T2 contents to be evaluated with SM=7 and p=0.3 and return 0.09 and not a summation expression?

Comment: The call to `ev` needs to include the argument `nouns` to verbify the noun expression. Try `ev(T2, SM = 7, p = 0.3, nouns)`.

Comment: please add this explicitly in the outline.  I read it and missed it.